# is it bayesian to calibrate probabilities

Tags: bayesian, calibration

I am getting introduced to Bayesian framework for modelling. I generally use `glm` models for large datasets of the order ~10m. While I understand that it may not make much difference if I use frequentist or bayesian approach for modelling such a large data. However I also use Naive Bayes to calibrate the resulting posterior probabilities.

Is this approach considered truly bayesian, irrespective of the size of the data?

Answer (score 1):

Calibration isn't exactly the same thing in Bayesian work.  The prior is where external data is brought to bear in the problem.  If you have some problem where there is substantial knowledge and it is credible to believe that $\mu_x\in[4,5]$ then you would put nearly all your mass in that range.  If so much data had accumulated that there was very little meaningful error, such as for the speed of light, then you could condition on a precise value such as $\mu_x=4.6321$.

As the posterior contains all the available information regarding the location of the parameters, all future work should be calibrated against *your* posterior density.  This would then be subject to scoring to test the validity of the model and its associated parameters from out of sample data.  Calibration on the Bayesian side is tied to model selection and model averaging.  As a consequence, the best out-of-sample fit may not be the model selected as the Bayesian mechanism will implicitly consider the possibility your validation set happens to be a non-representative sample.